# How do I call the write syscall using inline assembler in GCC under MacOS X?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, system-calls, inline-assembly

The `write` syscall has the following functional prototype:

```
size_t write(int, const void *buf, size_t nbytes);
```

How do I call the `write` syscall using inline assembler in GCC under MacOS X?

Comment: What would be the advantage over using the standard C `write` function?

Comment: @BoPersson Practical advantage? None, obviously. Learning advantage? Plenty.

Comment: On the nitpicker side: POSIX doesn't standardize the _syscall interface_, but merely the _system library interface_ ; the actual calling interface isn't defined as documented nor stable, and in fact there might be multiple methods - the BSD, Solaris and Linux kernels, for example, simultaneously support several (the old `int $0x80` and/or `lcall 0x27:0` ones as well as Intel/AMD `sysenter` / `syscall`). MacOSX has the "privilege" there of only supporting x86 hardware that has the `syscall` instruction ... and hence not bothering with any other...

Comment: @FrankH. True - I've updated the question accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the return value is actually `ssize_t`, not `size_t` (on MacOS X).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A generic solution to this type of question: Write a short test program doing the write() call you are interested in, and then use `gcc -S` to produce assembly or use `otool` to disassemble the binary; find out how the write() call was assembled and transform that into the appropriate inline assembly.

(edit) To see the actual syscall, follow the library call in the assembly code. In the example of `write()`, following the indirections will lead you via `libSystem.B.dylib` to `_write` in `libsystem_kernel.dylib`, which you can disassemble using `otool`.

(edit2) Full example below, using this test program `test.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char buf[] = "test\n";
    ssize_t n;
    n = write(2, buf, sizeof(buf));
    return n;
}
```

Compile and test, using `-O1 -fverbose-asm` to get concise, readable machine code:

```
% gcc -O1 -fverbose-asm -o test test.c
% ./test
test
```

Use `otool` to disassemble `main()` in the `test` binary:

```
% otool -p _main -tvV test
test:
(__TEXT,__text) section
_main:
0000000100000ef0    pushq   %rbp
0000000100000ef1    movq    %rsp,%rbp
0000000100000ef4    subq    $0x10,%rsp
0000000100000ef8    leaq    0xfa(%rbp),%rsi
0000000100000efc    movb    $0x74,0xfa(%rbp)
0000000100000f00    movb    $0x65,0xfb(%rbp)
0000000100000f04    movb    $0x73,0xfc(%rbp)
0000000100000f08    movb    $0x74,0xfd(%rbp)
0000000100000f0c    movb    $0x0a,0xfe(%rbp)
0000000100000f10    movb    $0x00,0xff(%rbp)
0000000100000f14    movl    $0x00000002,%edi
0000000100000f19    movl    $0x00000006,%edx
0000000100000f1e    xorb    %al,%al
0000000100000f20    callq   0x100000f32 ; symbol stub for: _write
0000000100000f25    addq    $0x10,%rsp
0000000100000f29    popq    %rbp
0000000100000f2a    ret
```

List the libraries `test` is dynamically linked against to find `_write`:

```
% otool -L test
test:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
```

Try to locate `_write` in `libSystem.B.dylib`:

```
% otool -p _write -tvV /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib:
(__TEXT,__text) section
Can't find -p symbol: _write
```

Check the dependencies of `libSystem.B.dylib`:

```
% otool -L /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib:
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 159.1.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 47.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 55010.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 6.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 85.1.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 187.9.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libdnsinfo.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 395.11.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 195.6.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libkeymgr.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 23.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/liblaunch.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 392.38.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libmacho.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 800.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libmathCommon.A.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 2026.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libquarantine.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 36.6.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libremovefile.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 21.1.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_blocks.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 53.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 763.13.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_dnssd.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_info.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1699.26.8)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_network.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 80.1.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libsystem_sandbox.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libunc.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 24.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libunwind.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 30.0.0)
    /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 77.19.0)
```

Guess that `_write` is probably contained in `libsystem_kernel.dylib` (or alternatively try all of them):

```
% otool -p _write -tvV /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib | head -20
(__TEXT,__text) section
_write:
0000000000017fd4    movl    $0x02000004,%eax
0000000000017fd9    movq    %rcx,%r10
0000000000017fdc    syscall
0000000000017fde    jae 0x00017fe5
0000000000017fe0    jmp cerror
0000000000017fe5    ret
0000000000017fe6    nop
0000000000017fe7    nop
[...]
```

Now we have all the assembly we need to construct the inline assembly version of `test`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char buf[] = "test\n";
    ssize_t n;
    asm volatile (
        "movl $0x00000002, %%edi\n"  /* first argument */
        "movl $0x00000006, %%edx\n"  /* third argument */
        "movl $0x02000004, %%eax\n"  /* syscall number */
        "syscall\n"
        : "=A"(n)         /* %rax: return value */
        : "S"(buf));      /* %rsi: second argument */
    return n;
}
```

Compile and test:

```
% gcc -O1 -fverbose-asm -o test-asm test-asm.c
% ./test-asm
test
```

That seems to work. The inline assembly above is not very refined; for example, you could pass in the first and third arguments dynamically as well, instead of hardcoding them in the assembly code.

Comment: MInd that this will show the call to the library's syscall wrapper function. It won't show the actual call to the kernel. WHich missing most of the fun of calling into kernel space, but I know too little about Darwin/Mach/...  to answer

Comment: True, depending on what the OP wants to achieve the actual syscall is needed; I've edited my solution accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The Linux solution is something like this:

```
.data mytext:
    .ascii "Hello World\n"  
.text 
  _mywrite:
    movl $0x04,         %eax     # Syscall No. 4 = write
    movl $0x01,         %ebx     # File. 1 = stdout 
    movl $mytext,       %ecx
    movl $0x0c,         %edx     # text length (hope I counted correctly)
    int  $0x80                   # Interrupt 0x80 -> make syscall
```

Should be similar on other Unix systems like Mac, but better check the syscall number (0x04) in the documentation.